# How can I make my traversal methods for Binary Search Trees return the string in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, methods, return, binary-search-tree

I've created two void methods that prints out the `inorder` traversal and the mirrored breadth first traversal of a binary search tree. However, I only got them to print out the result, I now want to use a buffered writer to write the result in a text file. What is the best way to do that?

```
    public void inorder(BSTNode<T> p) {
        if (p != null) {
            inorder(p.left);
            System.out.print(p.el + " ");
            inorder(p.right);
        }
    }

    public void mirrorBreadthFirst() {
        BSTNode<T> p = root;
        Queue<BSTNode<T>> queue = new Queue<BSTNode<T>>();
        if (p != null) {
            queue.enqueue(p);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                p = queue.dequeue();
                System.out.print(p.el + " ");
                //opposite of breadth first (reading from right to left):
                if (p.right != null)        
                    queue.enqueue(p.right);
                if (p.left != null)
                    queue.enqueue(p.left);
            }
    }
```

Those are my two methods (note: p.el is the element of node p).

I tried storing the value of (p.el) in an ArrayList then returning it using `toString` but it didn't work when I tried using `System.out.println(mirrorBreadthFirst());` in my `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to write to a file using the `BufferedWriter` class. You can use this instead of (or in addition to) logging to the console with `System.out`:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final String s = "This is the data in the output file";

    try (final BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/output.txt"));)
    {
        output.write(s);
    }
}
```